# how to remove Stack Navigation From First Home Screen in react native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
  <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login"   screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#1e42f4',
        },
        headerTitleAlign:'center',
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
      }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{
          title: 'My home',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#1e42f4',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
         
        }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Dash" component={Dash} options={{ title: "Dashboard", headerTitleAlign:'left', }} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

i want to remove Top Navigation Menu From My Login Screen. i'm using react-navigation version :6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide top header in Login Screen then you can pass `headerShown`
prop to options object and give it the value `false`

Code :

```
<Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{
    title: 'My home',
    headerStyle: {
       backgroundColor: '#1e42f4',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',   
    headerShown : false 
    }} 
/>
```